# SMTP connection hanging with Erlang (TCP and/or SSL) after first 220 code message

Tags: ssl, tcp, smtp, gmail, erlang

I'm trying to study TCP and SMTP, so I'm trying to write a TCP REPL in Erlang.

I don't know much about SMTP (or TCP), I'm still studying so if I say something absurd about (or if I'm trying to do something absurd) I ask you sorry.
For testing, I'm trying to connect to Gmail.

From the Gmail support page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en

> Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server

- smtp.gmail.com
- Requires SSL: Yes
- Requires TLS: Yes (if available)
- Requires Authentication: Yes
- Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

It's written that SSL is required, TLS is optional ("if available") and that the TLS port is 587.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29022120/2376736), it's said that port 587 is initially unencrypted, so I tried to start a plain tcp communication:
[image]

As you can see I start the communication and I receive a 220 response successfully, but when I try to answer it, the tcp connection hangs.

So, I thought that it might be hanging because although port 587 supposedly starts unencrypted, the support page says it requires SSL...

So I'm trying to use SSL/TSL with Erlang but I had not much success:

[image]

I'm trying to discover what this "unsupported_record_type" means but I still have no clue.

Let me show you the code, what I've tried so far:

```
print("Starting TCP Client~n", []),
  
ok = ssl:start(),
{ok, SSLSocket} = ssl:connect(AddressName, Port, [], infinity),
print("Connected to ~p:~p~n", [AddressName, Port]),
```

Since it failed, I tried to generate a ssl certification/key with the following:
`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`

Then I've tried the following connection (passing a TCP socket to upgrade):

```
{ok, TLSSocket} = ssl:connect(Socket, [{certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "key.pem"}], infinity).
```

And also:

```
{ok, TLSSocket} = ssl:connect(AddressName, Port, [{certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "key.pem"}], infinity).
```

But it generates the same error from the previous image.

1. Is it possible to establish a SMTP connection to Gmail without
   SSL/TSL? With so, why it might be hanging?

Initially I thought that it might some kind of timeout because of the repl waiting for me to enter the next TCP message, but I've tried a direct reply without the REPL approach and it hanged as well.

2. Why is this SSL connection failing? Did I generated the
   certification/key wrong? There is some easy way to establish this
   SSL connection?

Seems like that trying to use SSL is a recurrent problem for beginners.

Comment: Are you actually sending `"helo\r"` to the server? It needs both the CR and the LF, so that should be `"helo\r\n"`. Also, when connecting to port 587, you need to send the `STARTTLS` command before starting the TLS negotiation. See [the example in the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207#section-5).

Comment: Thank you very much, you're right, the LF made it right. I still failing connecting via SSL or negotiating the TSL. But your help already made it way better.

Comment: As you mentioned port 587 is a plain TCP port. I think SMTP servers enforce upgrading to TLS after initial communication to ensure the connection security, so I think upgrading an existing TCP connection to TLS would work: https://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#connect-2. This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049483/901161.